Converting laser irradiance into volume energy density
If I want to convert a laser's irradiance of $10^{20} \,\text{W}/\text{cm}^2$ into a volume energy density, do I just divide it by the speed of light $c$?

Dividing by $c$, when dimensionally correct, is usually a good bet with light.
However, doing it willy nilly may answer the wrong question. (see below).
To answer your question. We can imagine your beam has power $P=10^{20}$W in a spot w/ area $A=1$ sqaure-cm, for an irradiance $E_e=P/A$, and it pulses for $t=1$ second, so now you have $E=Pt=10^{20}$ J distributed across a volume:
$$ V = A \times (ct) $$
for an energy density:
$$ U = \frac{E}{V} = \frac{Pt}{ct A} = \frac{It}{ct} = I/c $$
which validates your original conjecture.
On to my quip: Suppose someone asked, what is the momentum irradiance of your laser?
You'd say, "Hmmm.. irradiance is radiant flux per unit area, and radiant flux is radiant energy per unit time, and radiant energy is...energy..." Well, we can use Poynting's Vector..or just count photons. Each photon carries an energy $h\omega$, and it also has a momentum $hk$, and we know $\omega = ck$, so why not just divide by $c$. Answer:
$$ {\rm Momentum\ irradiance}=I/c $$

Actually yes that's the correct answer but it should be read: the irradiance times the inverse of the speed of light, or the time it takes for light to travel 1 meter. This way we'll get the proper volume energy density.
